# Show related model info in Django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Say, for example, I have two models:

```
class Person:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class PhoneNumber:
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

So, when a user is going to modify a `PhoneNumber`, I'd like to show, in the form, the address of the person. I'm doing the editing through formsets, so that makes it passing the information directly to the template a bit trickier, how could I know which address belongs to which form? Or how else could I achieve this? This should be shown in a different place than the `ModelChoiceField`, since I want it to be hidden.

Comment: Can you add code where you want to show the address? If you have access to the `PhoneNumber` object you can simple do `pn.person.address` where `pn` is of type `PhoneNumber`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your template is it possible to loop over the forms in a formset. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates.

So I would make a FormSet containing PhoneNumber modelforms. While looping over the forms, use `form.instance.person.address`.

Comment: Btw, small tip, when getting the instances for the formset, do a select related on `person`, because now for every form a query is done to get a `Person`-object.

Comment: Hmmmm that's a fair point, I didn't even know about that. Thanks!